# What is the effective capacitance of this circuit?

Tags: capacitor, parallel

I'm trying to work out, in general terms, the effective capacitance of this circuit between Out_1 and Out_2:

[image]

What is the effective capacitance of this circuit and will the resistors affect the capacitance or can they be ignored in the analysis?

Comment: Can you use dot symbols where wires join because it is confusing to try and work out if 90º crossing wires connect or don't. What two points on the circuit are you trying to calculate the capacitance and is this with ground and Vin disconnected or connected to each other? Capacitance is mutually exclusive to resistance no matter how large the resistor is.

Comment: I'll remember to use dot symbols in future, but here you can assume that if wires cross, the connect.  I'm trying to workout the capacitance between Out_1 and Out_2.  Won't the resistance make the capacitors imperfect and leak charge?

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: There is no excuse for laziness. The site obviously encourages good answers but, questions are also encouraged to be succint and self-contained without ambiguity. Questions that are obscure are also encouraged to provide more information as to what they are about too. Your question is about an obscure circuit of components that wouldn't appear to have much relevance to anyone. I am asking you to improve this question by correcting the circuit diagram and now I'm asking you to provide some background information about this circuit. It's up to you.

Comment: No its not homework.  And woah, woah, woah @Andyaka, no need to get so aggressive.  I didn't think this would be such a big deal.  Its an obscure circuit its a representation/reduction.  The relevance is only to me, but the learning points for others would be if and how the resistors affect the total capacitance and how to solve given the V1,GND nodes in the middle such that its not a straight forward series/parallel reduction.  Perhaps I'm asking the wrong question and need to delete this one and start again, I don't know. But I don't want the whole thing solved, just this part

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "effective capacitance"? Obviously, the answer is going to depend strongly on the frequency of interest and the relative magnitudes of the component values. Without additional details, all you can do is write out the complete mesh equations and/or plug it into an analog circuit simulator.

Answer (score 1):

If one were to find the Thevenin impedance between the Out1 and Out2 nodes, the V1 source would be zeroed thus connecting the V1 and GND nodes together.

Denoting \$Z_1 = R_1 + \dfrac{1}{j\omega C_1}\$, the Thevenin impedance is, by inspection:

\$(Z_1||Z_3||Z_5 + Z_2||Z_4||Z_6)||\dfrac{1}{j\omega C_7} \$

At high enough frequencies, this expression is approximately \$\dfrac{1}{j\omega C_7} \$ and so one might say that the "effective" capacitance is just C7 for high enough frequencies.

At low enough frequencies, where the real part of each impedance is negligible, this expression is approximately:

\$(\dfrac{1}{j\omega C_1}||\dfrac{1}{j\omega C_3}||\dfrac{1}{j\omega C_5} +  \dfrac{1}{j\omega C_2}||\dfrac{1}{j\omega C_4}||\dfrac{1}{j\omega C_6})||\dfrac{1}{j\omega C_7}\$

so, for low enough frequencies, the "effective capacitance" is approximately:

\$(C_1 + C_3 + C_5)||(C_2 + C_4 + C_6) + C_7\$

At frequencies in-between these extremes though, where the impedance is a complicated function of frequency, I don't see how the notion of an equivalent capacitance is particularly helpful or meaningful.

Comment: What about GND - this will negate any analysis of C3, C4, C5 and C6 i.e. any signal appearing on OUT1 (ignoring C7 and C1) will not appear on OUT2 and, because the OP says V1 is a fixed voltage, you can ignore C1 and C2.

Comment: @Andyaka, the question is about the effective capacitance *between* Out1 and Out2.  The signal appears *across* Out1 and Out2, i.e., conceptually, we're driving Out1 and Out2 with a floating source and determining the impedance the source "sees".

Comment: I'm really not sure the OP has any idea what he is asking at all.

Comment: @Andyaka, I think he has an inchoate idea of what's being asked.  This is why I chose to answer the question from the perspective of the Thevenin equivalent impedance.  Looking at the expression for the impedance, it's clear that no clear notion of "effective capacitance" between Out1 and Out2 exists except at the frequency extremes where the impedance is approximately pure capacitive reactance.

Comment: Thanks Alfred Centauri for your understanding.  I realise that this question is somewhat half baked, but I'm trying to figure out the larger puzzle for myself (unsuccessfully) and given that its part of a project of mine, I'd feel it was cheating if it was all solved for me.  I've taken your answer on board its given me a lot to think about.  Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Just to prove I'm not aggressive and to help you see how badly you have phrased the question I'll show you my answer: -

> I am assuming GND is constant. V1 does change and sets the variable
>   capacitor, but it can be assumed to be constant for analysis since it
>   is DC

The above quote is taken from your reply to @JoeHass.

Quite simply the capacitance between out1 and out2 is C7, because GND prevents any signal conduction between the two points thus negating any meaningful examination of C3, C4, C5 and C6 and V1 being fixed also negates any meaningful examination of C1 and C2.

This analysis is based upon your quoted comment above. Should you wish to back-track on this (don't worry I won't get aggressive but I might point-out that you are wasting people's times with a badly phrased question with little thought) and suggest V1 is sourced from a high impedance node (as you would with varactor type tuning) then things look a little different but still C3, C4, C5 and C6 are not part of the analysis because they all connect to ground.

The answer you have accepted is wrong I believe.

Comment: Hey buddy, I agree it might be a badly phrased question, but I didn't appreciate the tone of your comment. There did not appear to be any charity in it. Alfred Centauri on the otherhand does seem to understand that I'm still grappling with the issue myself. I took time to think about the post before I submitted, but its only in the comments and answers that I've begun to really understand how much I don't understand. This was supposed to be a small piece of a larger puzzle. If Im still stuck, I will be back and then this question might make sense. But please be patient with me in the mean time

Comment: @E_L I'm not bothered how you appreciate the tone of my answers. As for charity, this is a site for raising and answering questions on electrical engineering and charity has little to do with stuff. I'm a patient guy for sure but please do listen to advice.

Comment: I did listen to your advice, I said that I would change my diagram for next time (I don't have enough privilege to add pictures myself and I tried using a tikzpicture but I'm guess the site doesn't render latex commands (or I wasn't doing it right)).

Comment: And Charity has everything to do with it.  Cause otherwise you end up alienating people rather than having them on side!  If you truly believe in the stack exchange principles of community then alienating people rather than trying to bring them in to the fold is not the way to do it.

Comment: @E_L thanks for the lecture dude. Now go and understand your problem and impress me when you come back with it updated. That's my type of old fashioned management style.